# Lua debug hooks seems to prevent the coroutine from working

Tags: lua, coroutine

So, I'm trying to build a multitasking system in lua that hands control back to the main thread at regular intervals.
The issue is that `debug.sethook` seems to cause the coroutines to die immediately when you set it to call `coroutine.yield`.

Setting to do something else appears to work properly.

```lua
o=coroutine.create(function()
   print("Hello")
   print("goodbye")
end)
debug.sethook(o,coroutine.yield,"l",1)
coroutine.resume(o)--No output here
print(coroutine.status(o))--prints dead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It happens in a near minimal context as well, so I simplified the example code.

Comment: You'll have to simplify your example that still reproduces the issue. There is too much going on that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Thanks for the advice, do you think the new example is simple enough right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the result of `resume` call, you'll see something like `false  attempt to yield across a C-call boundary`, so the execution fails, as you are trying to `yield` from the debug hook, which you can't do (you'll need to return from the debug hook). You can `resume` from the debug hook into a different coroutine and yield from there, but you can't yield from the hook.

Maybe a different solution can be recommended if you explain what you are trying to do (in an edit).

Comment: I'm trying to emulate a multi-process environment which allows coroutines to run alongside each other in a more... time-sliced fashion. I've acheived this with posix timers for now, and it works well enough that I'm fine with it.
Also yeah, you're right :)

Answer (score 2):

library that will yield when you return true in the hook that been set with `debug.sethook(co, function() return true end, "y")`

the library is enough to create multitask lua system
just run `require("yieldhook")` at very first of your code
further info at the git

https://github.com/evg-zhabotinsky/yieldhook

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing, since this approach appeared to be the wrong one to take, was what I found reading [this article on lua signal handling](http://boston.conman.org/2015/05/20.1), and what I found on this [email thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-06/msg00513.html).

Essentially I had to set up a posix timer to send a signal to my process whenever I wanted it to potentially interrupt the execution to switch to another coroutine, setup a hook to call lua_yield on the relevant thread state.

This allows me to emulate some of the multiprocessing features that I was looking for, and happens to be fairly fast, which is very nice.